# How to combine two directed graphs with different edge colors

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given the following directed graphs:

```
ClearAll[one, two];
one = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1};
two = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4};
```

I generate a single directed graph by:

```
Graph[Join[one, two], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

It is fine. When I assign different colors for each graph like `Blue` for `one` and `Red` for `two` and ask for a layered graph plot, it does not work!
I tried `EdgeAdd`, `GraphUnion` but no success. Any idea about the feasibility of such a custom-designed graph? I also consulted with `IGraphM`, hoping that it might have developed the code I am after, but again no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add colors as tags to the edges:

```
taggededges = MapIndexed[DirectedEdge @@ 
   Append[List @@ #, 
    If[#2[[1]] <= Length@one, Red, Blue]] &] @ 
  Join[one, two]
```

[image]

```
Graph[taggededges, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge[a_, b_, c_] :> c}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks as usual for your excellent code. My depository of MMA codes are full of yours!

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[one, two];
one = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1};
two = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4};

Legended[
 Graph[Join[
   Style[#, Magenta] & /@ Intersection[one, two],
   Style[#, Blue] & /@ Complement[one, two],
   Style[#, Red] & /@ Complement[two, one]], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{Blue, Magenta, Red}, {"one", "one && two", "two"}],
  {.3, .8}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Inspired by @kglr's excellent answer. A form which is easier for me to understand:

```
Legended[
 Graph[
  Join[
   one /. (x_ -> y_) ->
     Style[DirectedEdge[x, y, ""], Blue],
   two /. (x_ -> y_) ->
     Style[DirectedEdge[x, y], Red]]],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"one", "two"}],
  {.3, .8}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For a [`LayeredGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LayeredGraphPlot.html)

```
Legended[
 LayeredGraphPlot[
  Join[
   one /. (x_ -> y_) -> Style[
      DirectedEdge[x, y, ""], Blue],
   two /. (x_ -> y_) -> Style[
      DirectedEdge[x, y], Red]],
  PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled"],
 Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red},
   {"one", "two"}], {.3, .3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and answers. I can follow your answer with my limited knowledge of programming. kglr's excellent answer is certainly way beyond my programming boundary.

Comment: This is not a request but a note. Using kglr's code, I can generate a layered graph easily by : `LayeredGraphPlot[taggededges, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge[a_, b_, c_] :> c}, ImageSize -> 350]`. I tried some versions of your code to do the same but could not do it.

Comment: Very nice! I tried it before writing you but somehow it did not work. It seems that I made a mistake somewhere. Thank you very much for the code.